# CircleImageView on older versions. Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am running my app on a phone with android version 6.0.1 it is working perfect but when the same app is being run on the phone with android version 4.4.4
then it shows the following error:

```
06-20 16:40:49.118 10785-10785/com.example.priya.bestdeals E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.priya.bestdeals, PID: 10785
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.priya.bestdeals/com.example.priya.bestdeals.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                             at com.example.priya.bestdeals.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:266)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.priya.bestdeals.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:266) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                                                                             at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.priya.bestdeals.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:266) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.priya.bestdeals.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:266) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200b8 a=-1 r=0x7f0200b8}
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2109)
                                                                             at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
                                                                            at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImag
```

Here is the xml code of layout which uses the navigation view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
    <!--app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:onClick="gotoprofile"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/writelayout">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/write"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Write"
                android:onClick="gotowrite"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/deletelayout">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_delete_black_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Delete"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logoutlayout">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:onClick="gotowrite"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@mipmap/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
        android:indicatorStart="200dp"
        android:indicatorRight="230dp"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

here is the nav_header_main file I am using which has a circular imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/profilebackgrd"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="12dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user_image"
    android:id="@+id/etuserimage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user100"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Name"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
```

Comment: The real error is at the bottom of the stacktrace. I've updated accordingly. Older versions of Android don't use vector graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real error is **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)** it means your using vector image which is not supported my the android OS on your device.

Android 4.4 (API level 20) and lower doesn't support vector drawables. If your minimum API level is set at one of these API levels, you have two options when using Vector Asset Studio: generate Portable Network Graphic (PNG) files (the default) or use the Support Library.

If you want to use vector drawables only, you can use Android Support Library 23.2 or higher. This technique requires a change to your build.gradle file before you run Vector Asset Studio, as described in Support Library Backward Compatibility. The VectorDrawableCompat class in the Support Library allows you to support VectorDrawable in Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher.
[This Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) will help you more.

Comment: It worked very well for me and the explanation is neat